# Spliting the location column into Zipcode, Latitude and Longitude

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, ggmap

I have a column in my data frame which has the zipcode, latitude and Longitude

Location

```
"10007 (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635)"
"10002 (40.71612146793143, -73.98583147024613)"
"10012 (40.72553802086304, -73.99789641059084)"
"10009 (40.72664935898081, -73.97911148500697)"
```

I need to separate them into three different columns like Zipcode, Latitude and Longitude.

I tried to doing this

```
extract(Location, c("Zip-Code","Latitude", "Longitude"), "\\(([^,]+), ([^)]+)\\)")
```

I want to use the latitude and longitude to plot the map using ggmap

Thanks

Comment: Try `library(tidyr); separate(df1, Location, into = c("Zip_Code", "Latitude", "Longitude"), sep=",*\\s+\\(*|\\)", merge="extra")`

Comment: its different rows its not in the same row,

i tried your solution "it says invalid column specification"

Comment: I meant 10007 and (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635)"  in next line or same line?  My solution was based on the assumption that `"10007 (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635)"`

Comment: `unlist(strsplit(xxx, "(,|\\(|\\))"))` should help. extract just the 1st, 3rd and 4th from it then

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to `separate` be `extra="merge"` (or `extra="drop"`) instead of `merge="extra"`?

Comment: @aichao You are right it should be `extra="drop"`  I forgot what it was :-)

Comment: i have just edited my example,Yes the 10007 (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635) is in the same row

Comment: @KarthikSuresh i have updated my comment

Comment: @KarthikSuresh  In that case, it works perfect for me using `tidyr_0.6.0` and of course change to `extra="drop"`

Comment: @akrun : i tried your new solution it still shows the same error i am using the same package tidyr_0.6.0

Comment: @KarthikSuresh  I assume the dataset object name as `df1` and the column name as "Location"  If your dataset name is Location and column name is something else, make those changes

Comment: @akrun : yes i understand,

separate(GasCons,Location, into = c("Zip_Code", "Latitude", "Longitude"), sep=",*\\s+\\(*|\\)", extra="drop")

this is what i tried

Comment: Could you update your post with the `dput` output of the first 4 rows you showed i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(GasCons,4)))`

Comment: structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "10001\n(40.75025902143676, -73.99688630375988)", class = "factor"), 
    `Building type` = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Commercial", 
    "Residential"), class = "factor"), `Consumption(therms)` = c(58338L, 
    1476126L, 7191956L, 4628579L), `Consumption(GJ)` = c(6155L, 
    155740L, 758792L, 488341L), `Data Source` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ConEd", class = "factor")), .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic regex extraction:

```
library(purrr)

c("10007 (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635)", "10002 (40.71612146793143, -73.98583147024613)",
  "10012 (40.72553802086304, -73.99789641059084)", "10009 (40.72664935898081, -73.97911148500697)") %>%
  stringi::stri_match_all_regex("([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]+\\(([[:digit:]\\.\\-]+),[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]\\.\\-]+)\\)") %>%
  map_df(dplyr::as_data_frame) %>%
  dplyr::select(zip=V2, latitude=V3, longitude=V4)
## # A tibble: 4 × 3
##     zip          latitude          longitude
##   <chr>             <chr>              <chr>
## 1 10007 40.71363051943297 -74.00913138370635
## 2 10002 40.71612146793143 -73.98583147024613
## 3 10012 40.72553802086304 -73.99789641059084
## 4 10009 40.72664935898081 -73.97911148500697
```

More readable:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat <- c("10007 (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635)",
         "10002 (40.71612146793143, -73.98583147024613)",
         "10012 (40.72553802086304, -73.99789641059084)", 
         "10009 (40.72664935898081, -73.97911148500697)")

zip <- "([[:digit:]]+)"
num <- "([[:digit:]\\.\\-]+)"
space <- "[[:space:]]+"
lp <- "\\("
rp <- "\\)"
comma <- ","

match_str <- zip %s+% space %s+% lp %s+% num %s+% comma %s+% space %s+% num %s+% rp

dat %>%
  stri_match_all_regex(match_str) %>%
  map_df(as_data_frame) %>%
  select(zip=V2, latitude=V3, longitude=V4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.tmp = "10007 (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635)"
```

For ZIP:

```
gsub('([0-9]+) .*', '\\1', s.tmp)
```

For latitude:

```
gsub('.*\\((.*),.*', '\\1', s.tmp)
```

For longitude:

```
gsub('.*, (.*)\\).*', '\\1', s.tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it almost works here,

i am able to seperate the Latitude and Longitude But the ZIP still has the entire row.

10007 (40.71363051943297, -74.00913138370635)   40.71363051943297  -74.00913138370635

the first is the ZIP using the code